# How to play a video using url in vuforia videoplayback app using youtube player activity

Tags: sample, vuforia

I am working on AR project with Vuforia sdk and following VideoPlayBack sample project, i just want to play video using youtube url.so iam add a youtube player activity class the project and pass a static videoid to the activity its working properly.....but the issue is iam deleted the previously presented videos from assests folder then app crashes.

how to stop the loading of videoplayerhelper class in Vuforia sample app:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    vuforiaAppSession = new SampleApplicationSession(this);

    mActivity = this;

    startLoadingAnimation();

    vuforiaAppSession
        .initAR(this, ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    // Load any sample specific textures:
    mTextures = new Vector<Texture>();
    loadTextures();

    // Create the gesture detector that will handle the single and
    // double taps:
    mSimpleListener = new SimpleOnGestureListener();
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getApplicationContext(),
        mSimpleListener);

    mVideoPlayerHelper = new VideoPlayerHelper[NUM_TARGETS];
    mSeekPosition = new int[NUM_TARGETS];
    mWasPlaying = new boolean[NUM_TARGETS];
    mMovieName = new String[NUM_TARGETS];

    // Create the video player helper that handles the playback of the movie
    // for the targets:
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TARGETS; i++)
    {
        mVideoPlayerHelper[i] = new VideoPlayerHelper();
        mVideoPlayerHelper[i].init();
        mVideoPlayerHelper[i].setActivity(this);
    }

    mMovieName[STONES] = "VideoPlayback/VuforiaSizzleReel_1.mp4";
    mMovieName[CHIPS] = "VideoPlayback/VuforiaSizzleReel_2.mp4";

    // Set the double tap listener:
    mGestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(new OnDoubleTapListener()
    {
        // Handle the double tap
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e)
        {
            boolean isDoubleTapHandled = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TARGETS; i++)
            {
                // Verify that the tap happens inside the target:
                if (mRenderer!= null && mRenderer.isTapOnScreenInsideTarget(i, e.getX(),
                    e.getY()))
                {
                    // Check whether we can play full screen at all:
                 if (mVideoPlayerHelper[i].isPlayableFullscreen())
                    {
                        // Pause all other media:
                        pauseAll(i);

                        // Request the playback in fullscreen:
                        mVideoPlayerHelper[i].play(true,
                            VideoPlayerHelper.CURRENT_POSITION);

                        isDoubleTapHandled = true;
                    }

                    // Even though multiple videos can be loaded only one
                    // can be playing at any point in time. This break
                    // prevents that, say, overlapping videos trigger
                    // simultaneously playback.

                    break;
                }
            }
             return isDoubleTapHandled;
        }


        public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e)
        {
            // We do not react to this event
            return false;
        }


        // Handle the single tap
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e)
        {
            boolean isSingleTapHandled = false;
           /// Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "single touch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Do not react if the StartupScreen is being displayed
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TARGETS; i++)
            {
                // Verify that the tap happened inside the target
                if (mRenderer!= null && mRenderer.isTapOnScreenInsideTarget(i, e.getX(),
                    e.getY()))
                {

                    Intent intent=new Intent(VideoPlayback.this,VideoActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("videoid", "yCt-YUbs7H4");
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    isSingleTapHandled = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return isSingleTapHandled;
        }
    });
}
```